# package ‘IsolationForest’ is not available

Tags: r, rstudio, isolation

I am trying to use the Isolation Forest package in R to run some code. I had RStudio 3.3.1 but I kept getting an error "package ‘IsolationForest’ is not available"! Looking at the description file it says it depends on R >= 2.0.0, so I got RStudio 2.15.2, instead. However, I get the same problem again. Can someone help me with this situation? I am using Windows 7 for RStudio 2.15.2

Comment: R and RStudio are not the same thing. The second is an interface to the first. The version numbers that you describe are for R, not RStudio. Furthermore, Isolation Forest is not available via CRAN. It is an old package (2009) [available from R-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=479). It probably also requires RTools to be installed.

Comment: I already have that version of R too. I have downloaded the tar file for the Isolation Forest package from R-forge, and RTools too. But I don't know how to install RTools though. Can you help me with that, please?

Comment: RTools on Windows should be as simple as opening the `.exe` file that you downloaded and following the prompts. After that try the installation instructions at the R-forge page: `install.packages("IsolationForest", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`.

Comment: When I run the RTools exe file I get the following error:

Error creating registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\Environment


RegCreateKeyEx failed; code 5.
Access is denied

Click Retry to try again, Ignore to proceed anyway, or Abort to cancel installation.

Comment: In that case you have some local Windows issues that we cannot troubleshoot here. Try web search for that error. Perhaps you need admin access rights?